# Import CSV file into Spark Dataset with a Column of Arrays (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a CSV dataset where one of the columns contain arrays. How do I import it into a Spark Dataset in Java using a schema that contains arrays?

I've tried the following (where the 3rd column is an array):

```
    // Import data data
    DataType arrayType = DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.StringType);

    StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
            DataTypes.createStructField("field1",  DataTypes.StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("field2", DataTypes.StringType, true),
            DataTypes.createStructField("field3", arrayType, false),
    });

    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("csv")
            .option("sep", "\t")
            .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss ZZ")
            .option("header", "true")
            .schema(schema)
            .load(filepath);
```

Comment: CSV format does not support array:
https://intellipaat.com/community/14798/spark-2-0-x-dump-a-csv-file-from-a-dataframe-containing-one-array-of-type-string

can you provide csv file record?

Comment: @pasha701 In the CSV file, the array is encoded as a string. For example, the array ['a','b'] would be saved as "['a','b']".

Answer (score 0):

Array column, stored in CSV as string, can be parsed to ArrayType with "from_json" function:

```
val csvFileContent = Seq(
  "ID\tArrayColumn",
  "1\t['a','b']",
  "2\t['c','d']"
).toDS()

val csvFileDataFrame = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter", "\t").csv(csvFileContent.as(Encoders.STRING))

csvFileDataFrame
  .withColumn("ArrayColumn", from_json(col("ArrayColumn"), ArrayType(StringType)))
```

Output:

```
+---+-----------+
|ID |ArrayColumn|
+---+-----------+
|1  |[a, b]     |
|2  |[c, d]     |
+---+-----------+
```